# How we can trigger when add class into div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div and add new class into this div when click the button. I want to trigger another function after adding that class into this div. How can I do this.

I have added new class into div after clicking event. But How can I trigger another function whether this added class exist only.

```
<div id="container">
    <button onclick="clickMe(this)">Click</button>
</div>

function clickMe(event) {
    $(event).parent.addClass('check');
}
```

Comment: why not calling it directly after `addClass` ?

Comment: This phrase is not a proper question. "But How can I trigger another function whether this added class exist only."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding new class into this div you can check whether this class is existing by using jquery 'hasClass'. Below code you can see how we can do it.

```
function clickMe(event) {
    $(event).parent.addClass('check');
    var checkExistClass = $("#container").hasClass("check");
    if(checkExistClass ){
       alert("Works");
    }
}
```

Now  you can call your new function inside this if condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button').addClass('check').delay(2000).queue(function( next ){

// call your function here after 2 seconds delay (if needed)
  if($( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "check" )) {
    next(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: @Nik no needed just providing a timeout, that is totally optional

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JQuery hasClass() method.

```
 if ($("mydiv").hasClass("myclass"))
 {
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to check the existence of the class in the element.

**Please Note:** `parent` is a method in jQuery, you have to specify `()` after the method name to access members/properties.

I will also request you to be careful in naming the parameter as you are passing the element itself, not the event into the function, this may lead to confusion.

```js
function clickMe(el) {
  $(el).parent().addClass('check');
  if($(el).parent().hasClass('check'))
    anotherFunc();
}
function anotherFunc(){
  console.log('anotherFunc called');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <button onclick="clickMe(this)">Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to add more functions... as many as you want!

```
function clickMe(event) {
    $(event).parent.addClass('check');
    anotherFunction();

}

function anotherFunction() {
  console.log('This happen after adding the class');
}
```